# Conditional statement in cloud-formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-eks

**Background**

I have the following cloud formation template that i am trying to use to spin up a EKS CLUSTER. I am having issues with the logging settings. I want to make them conditional so in the future a user can set a specific logging like say `api` to true or false and based on that it will be enabled or disabled.

```
Parameters:
  ClusterName:
    Type: String
  ClusterVersion:
    Type: Number
    AllowedValues: [1.21, 1.20, 1.19, 1.18]
  RoleArnValue:
    Type: String
  ListOfSubnetIDs: 
    Description: Array of Subnet IDs
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>
  ListOfSecurityGroupIDs:
    Description: Array of security group ids
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id>
  ApiLogging:
    Type: String
    AllowedValues: [true, false]
  AuditLogging:
    Type: String
    AllowedValues: [true, false]
  AuthenticatorLogging:
    Type: String
    AllowedValues: [true, false]
  ControllerManagerLogging:
    Type: String
    AllowedValues: [true, false]
  SchedulerLogging:
    Type: String
    AllowedValues: [true, false]
  
Conditions:
    ApiLoggingEnabled: !Equals [!Ref ApiLogging, 'true']
    AuditLoggingEnabled: !Equals [!Ref AuditLogging, 'true']
    AuthenticatorLoggingEnabled: !Equals [!Ref AuthenticatorLogging, 'true']
    ControllerManagerLoggingEnabled: !Equals [!Ref ControllerManagerLogging, 'true']
    SchedulerLoggingEnabled: !Equals [!Ref SchedulerLogging, 'true']


Resources:
  EKSCluster:
    Type: AWS::EKS::Cluster
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub ${ClusterName}
      Version: !Sub ${ClusterVersion}
      RoleArn: !Sub ${RoleArnValue}
      ResourcesVpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds: !Ref ListOfSecurityGroupIDs
        SubnetIds: !Ref ListOfSubnetIDs
      Logging:
        ClusterLogging:
            EnabledTypes:
              - Type: !If [ApiLoggingEnabled, api, 'AWS::NoValue']
              - Type: !If [AuditLoggingEnabled, audit, 'AWS::NoValue']
              - Type: !If [AuthenticatorLoggingEnabled, authenticator, 'AWS::NoValue']
              - Type: !If [ControllerManagerLoggingEnabled, controllerManager, 'AWS:NoValue']
              - Type: !If [SchedulerLoggingEnabled, scheduler, 'AWS:NoValue']


Outputs: 
  ClusterArn: 
    Description: Arn of EKS CLUSTER
    Value: !Ref EKSCluster
```

However i get the **following Error** My template works fine when i get rid of the logging stuff but i want to fix that. I am not sure what i did wrong.

```
  Properties validation failed for resource EKSCluster with message: #/Logging/ClusterLogging/EnabledTypes/2/Type: #: only 1 subschema matches out of 2 #/Logging/ClusterLogging/EnabledTypes/2/Type: failed validation constraint for keyword [enum] #/Logging/ClusterLogging/EnabledTypes/3/Type: #: only 1 subschema matches out of 2 #/Logging/ClusterLogging/EnabledTypes/3/Type: failed validation constraint for keyword [enum] #/Logging/ClusterLogging/EnabledTypes/4/Type: #: only 1 subschema matches out of 2 #/Logging/ClusterLogging/EnabledTypes/4/Type: failed validation constraint for keyword [enum]
```

Comment: How did it go? Still don't know why you got the error?

Answer (score 0):

It should be `!Ref 'AWS::NoValue'`:

```
      Logging:
        ClusterLogging:
            EnabledTypes:
              - Type: !If [ApiLoggingEnabled, api, !Ref 'AWS::NoValue']
              - Type: !If [AuditLoggingEnabled, audit, !Ref 'AWS::NoValue']
              - Type: !If [AuthenticatorLoggingEnabled, authenticator, !Ref 'AWS::NoValue']
              - Type: !If [ControllerManagerLoggingEnabled, controllerManager, !Ref 'AWS:NoValue']
              - Type: !If [SchedulerLoggingEnabled, scheduler, !Ref 'AWS:NoValue']
```